# Count IF function assistance

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, wps

[image: Example]

As shown above I am trying to count the cells which does not have 0 in it. But it still shows 6 where the desired output is 3. Am I doing something wrong here? This is such simple thing but I'm breaking my head over it.
This is the formula i entered

```
=COUNTIF(AS1:AX1,"<>""0")
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Try: `=COUNTIF(AS1:AX1,">0")` or `=COUNTIF(AS1:AX1,"<>0")`

Comment: There you go, why didnt this work `=COUNTIF(AS1:AX1,"<>""0")`?

Comment: It didnt work because you have double inverted quotes after `<>` and before `0` which doesnt considers not equal to and checks if the range is not blank

Comment: The value of  `"<>""0"` is `<>"0` which is not the correct comparision operation, evidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following as posted above in comments:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>AY1</kbd>

```
=COUNTIF(AS1:AX1,">0")
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>AZ1</kbd>

```
=COUNTIF(AS1:AX1,"<>0")
```

---

Your initial formula was not working since it was considering if not equal to blank instead of not equal to `0`. The criteria should be wrapped within the speechmarks/double inverted quotes `""`

---